# Play Framework JPA postgres

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, play-framework, persistência

Ola, estou aprendendo a trabalhar com Play! framework e estou tendo dificuldade de integrar minha aplicação com o banco Postgres, utilizando hibernate.
A aplicação não utiliza a persistencia, o banco esta funcionando pois se eu utilizo uma conexão padrão não ocorre erro algum.
Tentei vários tipos de config e muito já disparam erros antes mesmo de acessar a criação da conexão.
A config mais atual é:

application.config:

```
datasource="jdbc:postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db"
datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.jndiName=defaultPersistence
datasource.schema=dev

persistence.xml:

property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"
            property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" 
            property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sys_dev" 
            property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dev" 
            property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" 
            property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sql" 
            property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" 
            property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" 
            property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" 
            property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory"
```

Comment: Para minha aplicação modelo apenas quando eu uso o ds funciona.     db.default.driver = org.h2.Driver
db.default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.username = root
db.default.password = "" nenhuma outra configuração funciona

Comment: Descobri o problema. basta usar a versão "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41" da dependencia do postgresql, a versão que aparece em muitos exemplos inclusive no site ocorre problemas.